# Confusing about LU factorization process.

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does y = Ux. Where does this even come from?

[image]

Comment: You asked the exact same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870633/lu-factorization-process-a-bit-confused).  Please... be patient and wait for responses on the first time you ask the question rather than posting again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\boldsymbol A = \boldsymbol {LU}$, then the equation $\boldsymbol {Ax} = \boldsymbol b$ could be written as $\boldsymbol {LUx} = \boldsymbol b$. To solve this equation, we first **let** $\boldsymbol y = \boldsymbol {Ux}$, then we can first solve $\boldsymbol y$ from $\boldsymbol {Ly} = \boldsymbol b$, then solve $\boldsymbol x$ from $\boldsymbol {Ux} = \boldsymbol y$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for pointing out.